# Application not installed after running InstallShield installer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installshield

I am trying to figure out how to make an installer for a C# WPF. I followed [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb88b2/simple-steps-to-create-setup-file-using-install-shield-le-fr/) tutorial and I created the installer just fine using VS2015 and InstallShield LE. When I run it on my computer the installer comes up, goes through the steps, and everything installs just fine. When I run it on another computer the installer runs, but the application is not installed afterwards.

All the application is is the blank window that Visual Studio 2015 Professional creates when making an empty WPF project. The machine that it does not work on has .NET 4.5 installed, but not Visual Studio.

I have tried it on two other computers so far. Any insight?

Comment: So the application is installed, but it doesn't look the same?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The installer will run, but the application is not installed after the installer is done running.

Comment: coincidentally I had this exact same problem today for the first time using installshield.  It will work fine on my computer but when I install on other computers I get the blank window you are talking about.  I was using a Keybinding so that when I hit F1 a help menu would display.  When I removed this everything worked.  Haven't figured out why yet.

Comment: I don't even get a blank window. I actually just figured out what my issue was. I had only coped the executable to teh other computers, I need the entire folder it was in. I will answer my question as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. It was a misunderstanding as to how InstallSheild worked. I was just copying over the executable to the new computer, but I needed to copy over the entire folder that it is created in and run the executable from there.